# Android toast has strange shape

Tags: android, toast

When using toast messages in my app it appears in a wrong shape. The code I am using is:

```
Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.changeLanguageConf), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

[image: Toast wrong shape]

Do you know what could be the root cause? context is an argument passed as getContext() from a different procedure.

Comment: Your resource may have some style within he, try replace the resource text by an "hardcoded" String with the same text, like : `.makeText(context,"Language changed to English",....);`

Comment: I think it happens because of theme used

Comment: Strange problem, but nobody is going to be able to reproduce it with the code in the question. Have you tried that code in a test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the theme used. More specific it was due to:

```
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getContext(), try using getApplicationContext(). I would also try to get the context just before creating and showing the toast, as the following.

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.changeLanguageConf), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I highly doubt that which Context is used would have any effect on text alignment in a Toast......